# TUN interface created from C not showing up in ifconfig output

Tags: c, linux, networking, tun

I have written the following function that is supposed to create a TUN interface named "my_tun" on Linux:

```
int tun_open()
{
  int fd;
  if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) == -1) {
    return -1;
  }

  struct ifreq ifr;
  strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "my_tun", IFNAMSIZ);
  ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI;

  if (ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, &ifr) == -1) {
    return -1;
  }

  return fd;
}
```

I'm testing it by running it inside a Ubuntu docker container started with `--cap-add NET_ADMIN`. Inside this docker container I first execute:

```
mkdir /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
```

And the run my function. The latter does not fail yet afterwards `ifconfig` does not show a TUN interface, only an ethernet and a loopback interface. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check the source code of `ifconfig` tool.  It should contain correct code to create `tun` devices.  Use it as reference.

Most probably, the newest edition of "UNIX Network Programming" (Stevens et al.) should have a description somewher on how to create a tun device also.

Answer (score 0):

Try "ip link" and you might see it there provided code above didn't return -1. Also your interface is non-persistent therefore you need to keep the program running when u try ifconfig or IP link.
Try to add a sleep before "return fd" to buy time and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

By using the code you provided, a non persistent TUN interface would be created and, after your program exits, the TUN interface will be destroyed.

You can make it persistent by adding this to your code:

```
int result = ioctl(fd, TUNSETPERSIST, 1);
if (result == -1)
{
    printf("Unable to make TUN interface persistent\n");
}
```

Make sure to include `if_tun.h` for `TUNSETPERSIST`.